# Proof regarding Cauchy General Principle of Convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Using Cauchy's General Principle of convergence prove that {$n/n+1$} is convergent. i.e $|S_{n+p} - S_n| <$ is less than any positive real number , when $n\geq m$ , and $p\geq 1$

What i did was approach the sum like we do to prove non-convergence of sequences.
$$
\begin{align}
S_n &= 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 +...+ n/(n+1) \\
S_{n+p} &= 1/2 + 2/3 +...+ (n+p)/((n+p)+1) \\
S_{n+p} - S_n &= (n+1)/(n+1)+1 + ......+ (n+p)/((n+p)+1)
\end{align}
$$

At this point how can we prove that $S_{n+p} - S_n$ is less than any positive real number?

Comment: I think you are confusing the sequence with terms $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and the series with terms $\frac{n}{n+1}$. The former converges while the latter does not.

Comment: Actually i was using a approach used in our textbooks. I am aware that the series diverges but to prove that the sequence converges 'using' cauchy general principle of convergence i have to prove that \$S_n+p - S_n$\ is less than any positive real number

Comment: Could you add an image of the relevant section of the book? What you've written is false. If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $|a - b|$ is less than every positive real number if and only if $a = b$.